# Selenium and webdriver for IE11 not passing ajax call

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, internet-explorer-11

I am having difficulties to get my ajax call to come to the back end.

I am using webdriver 2.50.1 on windows 8 (well, i try them all from 2.44)

```
start java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.50.0.jar -Dwebdriver.ie.driver="C:\\selenium\IEDriverServer.exe" -role node -hub http://192.168.1.2:5555/grid/register
```

with a server on linux using the stand alone java server

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.50.1.jar -port 5555 -role hub -debug
```

But when I test the application. the Ajax calls done by the front end do not pass through to the back end.

Is there any setup to allow/disallow the ajax calls? for the IEwebDriver or the standalone server?
Thanks 
Note: only IE11 gives me problems (firefox, chrome work fine) but IE is used remotely the others are local.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a CORS problem. Ajax calls from the same URL are OK but if you make calls from different URL's the server needs to respond with the correct CORS headers. You can google a lot of results will appear for this.

Comment: thanks arisalexis , I have tried to add the     crossDomain: true,  inside the Ajax.Request javascript call but this doesn't change anything. Also I have now run the python test directly on the windows 8 machine and i got the same problem, No Ajax calls. But if I use firefox it is all fine.

Comment: for cross domain the server needs to return the correct headers too. If you have no ajax calls then this question is not about ajax calls and you need to rephrase it?

Answer (score 0):

In fact the problem wasn't the ajax call but the login to the app.
on chrome and firefox I use http://user:pass@ip/target but this is not fully working with IE.
with IE I need to remove the user:pass of the url and found another way to log.
Although this is strange as the app under IE is partially logged but not for the eye of IE ? 
The app (the back end) is logging us in but not IE (the browser), Probably some extra security feature of IE??